# Does the law of truly large numbers/infinite monkey theorem hold with an ever decreasing probability?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, binary

Recently I've been considering a game (I'm unsure if it has a proper name and is an already studied problem), and it proceeds as follows.

1. Flip a coin, selecting a value of either 0 or 1.
2. Append the result to the sequence of past flips.
3. If the last flip has marked the repetition of the past history of the sequence (i.e. the first half of the sequence now equals the second half), the game terminates.
4. Otherwise, keep playing the game.

Some example runs where the game terminates might be 11, or 00, or 101101, or 1001110011, etc. But the longer sequences get exponentially less likely to be repeated, for instance had the last example ended instead with a 0, we would then need to just by chance get the precise sequence of subsequent flips 1001110010 to form 1001110010[|]1001110010.

Thus after a certain point, it seems as though we are bound to keep failing forever, eternally making the required sequence we must repeat to finish the game longer and longer. And running some basic simulations of 1000 different random seeds for this game reveals a curious distribution of game lengths:

| Game Length | Occurrences (/1000) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 521 |
| 4 | 127 |
| 6 | 59 |
| 8 | 15 |
| 10 | 13 |
| 12 | 3 |
| 14 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 18 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 |
| > 1,000,000 | 257 |

Here the final category the game was manually terminated after iterating beyond 1 million in length (as these sequences seem to run forever or for a very long time). The rarest game lengths are actually the intermediate length games, with a decent portion falling into this exceedingly long case instead.

This pattern is interesting to me, and my question ultimately is, ***do these sequences truly run forever***? Past a certain point does this probabilistic game become truly hopeless, even though at each step as the sequence gets longer there is a non-zero probability of the past history of the sequence happening to exactly reoccur?

I liken this game by analogy to moving twice as far away from a quantum tunnelling particle every time it fails to tunnel to your location, which also seems to imply it would never catch you even given infinite time. Or perhaps if the works of Shakespeare expanded by an additional character with each wrong keypress by the monkey at the typewriter, multiplying the difficulty.

But at the same time this logic contrasts with my intuition about the law of truly large numbers, which says given infinite time any events with non-zero probability will eventually happen. So how is the law affected in the case where the probability in question is not constant, but eternally decreasing (halving with each failure in this case)?

Edit: As an interesting aside, if we instead roll a 10 sided die, the result from the long runs becomes a sequence of random digits, e.g. 943669542398...; and I notice by definition this sequence avoids repetitions, and so if we put a decimal point before it, 0.943669542398... for instance, we are essentially constructing an irrational number. The distribution also shifts such that the vast majority of runs end up in the long seemingly endless case.

Comment: If the definition of your event depends on the previous history then you don't have a sequence of independent trials and the law of truly large numbers doesn't apply. For a simpler example, let the game terminate iff the first flip comes up heads. That has a probability of 1/2, but if it doesn't happen on the first trial, it will never happen.

Comment: Even when there’s independence, if the event probability decays  faster asymptotically than $1/n^{1+\epsilon}$, there will be a nonzero probability that none of the events occur. (I’m not sure if analyzing this particular problem is quite that simple, though.)

Comment: Note that the probability that the game ends on the sixth coin toss, given that it did not end on the second or fourth tosses, is $1/6$ rather than $1/8$, because when you eliminate all sequences of $0$ and $1$ of length $4$ that would cause the game to end at the second or fourth toss, two out of three of the remaining sequences have the same digit as the first and last digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: *Do these sequences truly run forever?*

Answer: Yes. There is a finite probability that the process never ends. Let $E_n$ be the event that the game ends after exactly $2n$ flips. Note that
$$
n\ge 2\implies P(E_n)\le 2^{-n}-2^{-(n+2)}
$$
In order for $E_n$ to occur, the last $n$ flips must match the first $n$ flips, which occurs with probability $2^{-n}$. However, the $2^{-n}$ calculation includes sequences that would have ended after fewer than $2n$ flips. For example, any sequences which looks like this will be counted, even though it would have ended after the first two flips.
$$
0,0,\underline{\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{series of $n-2$ flips}\;\;\;\;\;\;},0,0,\underline{\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{same series of $n-2$ flips}\;\;}
$$
The probability of the above sequence is $2^{n-2}/2^{2n}=2^{-(n+2)}$. There are many other cases which need to be subtracted. However, subtracting only the above case gives an upper bound.

We then apply the union bound; the probability of at least one of the events $E_1,E_2,E_3,\dots$ occurring is at most the sum of their probabilities. This sum is at most
$$
P(\text{process eventually ending})\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)\le \frac12+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (2^{-n}-2^{-(n+2)})=\frac12+\frac12-\frac{1}{8}\le \frac78
$$
In particular, with probability at least $1/8=12.5\%$, the process will continue forever. Above, I used the infinite geometric series formula to compute the infinite sum.

Question: *How does this relate to the law of large numbers, which says that infinitely repeated events will certainly eventually occur?*

Answer: In general, if you have a series of **independent** events $E_1,E_2,\dots$ with the **same nonzero probability**, then you can be certain that these events will occur infinitely often. However, for your problem, the events are *dependent*. Also, the probabilities are not the same, but are *decreasing over time*. These two difference are why you get a different result.

It is possible to weaken the assumption about the same nonzero probability. In general, if $E_1,E_2,\dots$ is a sequence of **independent** events such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)=+\infty$, then you can conclude that infinitely many of the events will occur. This is the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. For example, if $P(E_n)=1/n$, then you can conclude that there will be infinitely many occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between the chance that one play of the game terminates, which is not governed by the law of large numbers, and the distribution of termination times, which is.  The law of large numbers says that the distribution of terminations in your simulation will match up (roughly) with the calculation below.

In one game, the chance of termination is $\frac 12$ after two flips. The chance of termination after $4$ flips is $\frac 1{8}$ because only $\frac 12$ of the time do you play after $2$ flips and you terminate after $4$ in $\frac 14$ of those.  The chance of termination after $6$ flips is already a bit hard to calculate as the chance the last three flips match the first three is influenced by the games where you stop before $6$ flips.  The sum of the chances you stop at all is clearly less than $1$ so there is a chance strictly greater than $0$ you never stop.

Comment: Continuing past the second flip has probability $1/2$, not $3/4$, to termination on the fourth flip has probability $1/8$, consistent with the simulation. Probability of termination on the sixth flip is $1/16$ -- see my comment under the question.

Comment: @DavidK:  you are right.  I have fixed it.  Can we say thaat the chance of stopping on flip $2k$ (after $k=1$) is $1/2^{k+1}$?  That would support a chance of never terminating of $\frac 14$

Comment: I find it surprising that the first three probabilities turn out to be in that geometric sequence. But maybe I shouldn't. I'll have to think about that. Does the pattern continue?

Answer (score -1):

For a given sequence of $1$ and $0$ of length $n$, the probability of a *repetition* = $\frac{1}{2^n}$

What happens as $n \to \infty$? In other words $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$ Looks like the answer is $0$. The *termination* of the *game* becomes less and less likely as *repetition* fails, but do note the probability of ending in $2$ "moves", $\frac{1}{2}$, is *greater than* the probability of ending after $4$ moves (e.g. 1010), which is $\frac{1}{2^4}$ Noting the OP's comment that $0000$ or $1111$ can't occur as they both terminate at $00$ and $11$. However, the probability I've calculated $(\frac{1}{16})$ must be multiplied by all the $4$ digit binary numbers which *do not* repeat for $4$ digits: $2 \times 1 \times 2 \times 1 = 4$ such numbers viz. $1000, 1001, 0100, 0111$, brings the probability up to $4 \times \frac{1}{16} = \frac{1}{4}$. **Most interesting**. I'm allowed to count $0000$ and $1111$ for the *2nd group* of 4 digit binary numbers.

Comment: This is not correct as the chance of stopping after $4$ flips is less than $\frac 14$ because of the times you would have stopped after $2$.  You are counting $0000$ and $1111$ as stopping after $4$ flips but they would have stopped after $2$.